# Bad Loop Confusion

Tags: c#, loops

I try to print n sequence of numbers, but I want to skip all numbers which at the end 3 has like: `3,13,23,33,43`; I want to ignore these numbers and get these numbers `1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15` as output. Thanks for your help.

```
int iBöseZahl;
Console.Write("Enter the Böse Number:");
iBöseZahl = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter the starter number:");
int iStarter = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter n long number:");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = iStarter; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (iBöseZahl != i)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}", i);
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why closed for "debugging details"? The problem and desired results are clear.

Comment: The modulo (%) operator will give you the remainder of dividing one number by another, so to find out if the number ends in 3, use  `if (iBoseZahl != (i % 10))`

Comment: @Benyam We have a [help] with all kinds of articles for that. I'd recommend the [ask] help page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  if ((i % 10) != 3)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: `if((i%10) != 3) Console.WriteLine(i);` - note `i` instead of `n`